# Cómo imprimo el contenido del array en lugar del número de localización al enviarlo a una hoja de calculo de google sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, lista

Tengo un formulario que posee tres selects dependientes (Estado, Municipio, Parroquia). Al enviar el formulario se carga automáticamente en una hoja de calculo de drive, todo se llena perfectamente con excepción de los selects que en lugar de imprimir en la hoja el estado, municipio y parroquia seleccionado imprime el número de localización del array.

Quiero que al envíar el formulario quede el impreso en la hoja de calculo el contenido en lugar del número del array

Así se ve en la hoja de calculo al envíar el formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el código en javascript de las listas

```
var arrItems1 = new Array();
            var arrItemsGrp1 = new Array();
        

        arrItems1[3] = "Alto Orinoco";
        arrItemsGrp1[3] = 1;

        arrItems1[4] = "Atabapo";
        arrItemsGrp1[4] = 1;
        arrItems1[5] = "Atures";
        arrItemsGrp1[5] = 1;
        arrItems1[6] = "Autana";
        arrItemsGrp1[6] = 1;
        arrItems1[7] = "Manapiare";
        arrItemsGrp1[7] = 1;
        arrItems1[8] = "Maroa";
        arrItemsGrp1[8] = 1;
        arrItems1[9] = "Rio Negro";
        arrItemsGrp1[9] = 1;
///son más


        var arrItems2 = new Array();
        var arrItemsGrp2 = new Array();
        

        arrItems2[341] = "Huachamacare";
        arrItemsGrp2[341] = 3
        arrItems2[342] = "Marawaka";
        arrItemsGrp2[342] = 3
        arrItems2[343] = "Mavaca";
        arrItemsGrp2[343] = 3
        arrItems2[344] = "Sierra Parima";
        arrItemsGrp2[344] = 3

        arrItems2[345] = "Caname";
        arrItemsGrp2[345] = 4
        arrItems2[346] = "Ucata";
        arrItemsGrp2[346] = 4
        arrItems2[347] = "Yapacana";
        arrItemsGrp2[347] = 4

        arrItems2[348] = "Fernando Girón Tovar";
        arrItemsGrp2[348] = 5
        arrItems2[349] = "Luis Alberto Gómez";
        arrItemsGrp2[349] = 5
        arrItems2[350] = "Parhueña";
        arrItemsGrp2[350] = 5
        arrItems2[351] = "Platanillal";
        arrItemsGrp2[351] = 5

        ///son más
        



        function selectChange(control, controlToPopulate, ItemArray, GroupArray)
        {
          var myEle ;
          var x ;
        

          for (var q=controlToPopulate.options.length;q>=0;q--) controlToPopulate.options[q]=null;
          console.log(Estado);
          
          if (control.id == "Estado") {
            
            for (var q=formdistribuidores.Parroquia.options.length;q>=0;q--) formdistribuidores.Parroquia.options[q] = null;
            console.log(Estado);
         }
          
          myEle = document.createElement("option") ;
          myEle.value = 0 ;
          myEle.text = "Selecciona" ;
          controlToPopulate.add(myEle) ;

          for ( x = 0 ; x < ItemArray.length  ; x++ )
            {
              if ( GroupArray[x] == control.value )
                {
                  myEle = document.createElement("option") ;
                  myEle.value = x ;
                  myEle.text = ItemArray[x];
                  controlToPopulate.add(myEle) ;
                
                }
            }
            

            
        }
        
        
        
        </script>
```

La función que activa el Google App Script es

```
<script>
  const scriptURL = '<SCRIPT URL>'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
</script>
```

Y la funcion que rellena la hoja de calculo con la información enviada es este

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Comment: Y la funcion con la que creas el documento drive? puedes ponerla?

Comment: sinceramente, solo se me ocurre que haga un input de tipo hidden, y que se rellene con el evento change del select, y este input es el que tienes que subir

Comment: Ya agregué las funciones donde se traslada la información drive